# Google Cloud Function - Python - Unable to decode gzip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am building a `Google Cloud Function` that will receive messages from a `Google PubSub` Topic.

While inserting messages in high volumes I am seeing in the logs of the function the following error:

```
('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check')), retrying in 1 seconds...
```

This happens for a few times inconsistently:

1. Does not happen to most of the messages
2. Inconsistent number of failures - from a single time to 40 times straight.

My messages are not gzip compressed and there is no "Content-Encoding" attribute in them.

My function code is not executed, this is happening on the gcp function backend before reaching my function code.

The function does work and the messages are executed, but I want to investigate why I am having this issue.

**Questions**

1. What could be the cause of this issue?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: To help you, follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved when I upgraded Python 3.7 to 3.8.

This seems like a bug in the function backend or some library used.